# A kind of ideals in Gorenstein local rings.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $(R,m)$ be a Gorenstein local ring. Then there exists an irreducible ideal $I\subset R$, such that $\sqrt I=m$, and $\operatorname{pd}_RI<\infty$.

I am looking for such $I$. Clearly, if such $I$ exists, $R/I$ has to be Gorenstein. And as an $R$-module, $R/I$ is of finite injective dimension.

I know such $I$ can't be $m$. Otherwise, $R$ has to be regular.

Comment: In any Cohen-Macaulay local ring. $R$, take $I$ to be an ideal generated by a maximal regular sequence. Then $R/I$ has finite projective dimension.

Comment: @Mohan So the Gorenstein condition implies $R/I$ is also Gorenstein, which means $I$ is irreducible, right?

Comment: Yes. Does that answer your questions?

Comment: @Mohan Yes, thanks,